# for-await-of simple example (typescript)

Tags: typescript

In typescript 2.3 a new feature was introduced as for-await-of can anyone post a simple example of how to use the same with promise and what is main use case of the same, i was looking into the example in there change log

```
async function f() {
  for await (const x of g()) {
 console.log(x);
 }
}
```

but could not understand much about the use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sample which uses for-await-of to print "1", wait a second and then print "2":

```
// Polyfill Symbol.asyncIterator
(Symbol as any).asyncIterator = Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol("Symbol.asyncIterator");

async function sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function* asyncGenerator() {
  yield 1;
  await sleep(1000);
  yield 2;
}

(async() => {
  for await (const num of asyncGenerator()) {
    console.log(num);
  }
})().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

The TypeScript 2.3 release notes have some [helpful caveats](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#the-for-await-of-statement)

- You need to include `esnext` in the `compilerOptions.lib` setting of your `tsconfig.json` (or in the `--lib` command line flag).
- You need to set `compilerOptions.downlevelIterators` in your `tsconfig.json` (or `--downlevelIterators` on the command line).
- You may need a `Symbol.asyncIterator` polyfill (included in the snippet above).

Comment: It's `Symbol.for("Symbol.asyncIterator")`