# How to return a Promise Function in For loop?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, promise

I have a function (sendEmail) as you see here:

```
public async sendEmail (log: LogMessage): Promise<void> {
nodemailer.createTestAccount(async () => {
      return ServiceFactory.getSystemService().getNetworkPreferences().then(async (networkPreferences) => {
....
```

I want to use it in a for loop:

```
for (const log of logs) {
          const timestamp = moment(log.creationDate)
          const startTime = new Date(Date.now())
          if ((timestamp.diff(startTime)) >= rule.miliSecond && category.includes(log.category)) {

            return this.sendEmail(log)
          }
        }
```

I cannot delete "return this.sendEmail(log)", because the function returns Promise. But the loop works just one time and with the first log, it would be terminated.
How can I use the function in this loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258568/for-await-of-simple-example-typescript

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should make a promise for `nodemailer.createTestAccount` and `await` that. Don't pass an `async function` as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put all the promises in an array and create a promise that completes when all the `sendEmail` promises complete.

```
sendAll() {
    let allMails: Promise<void>[] = [];
    for (const log of logs) {
        const timestamp = moment(log.creationDate)
        const startTime = new Date(Date.now())
        if ((timestamp.diff(startTime)) >= rule.miliSecond && category.includes(log.category)) {

            allMails.push(this.sendEmail(log));
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(allMails);
}
```

The version above launches all the requests in parallel. If you want to run `sendEmail` sequentially you can use async/await to wait while an email is ent before you send the next:

```
async sendAll() : Promise<void>{
    for (const log of logs) {
        const timestamp = moment(log.creationDate)
        const startTime = new Date(Date.now())
        if ((timestamp.diff(startTime)) >= rule.miliSecond && category.includes(log.category)) {

            await this.sendEmail(log);
        }
    }
}
```